# Method parameters in findall closure are empty

Tags: groovy

There is a method in code

```
def createdOrders = getValuesByStatus(extractedResponse, status)
```

Where `extractedResponse` is jsonSlurper parsed result and `status` just string value

Method:

```
def getValuesByStatus(def jsonData, String status ) {
        jsonData.findAll() { json->
            json.responseStatus.status == status
        }
    }
```

Testing with Spock this `getValuesByStatus` works perfectly, 
but running main application somehow results in

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'responseStatus' on null object
```

Running debug in intellij idea I can see that `jsonData` is not null and not empty, but breakpoint in findall closure showing that `json` element is null...

Comment: Try to change it to `findAll { json -> ... }`, without `()` parentheses.

Comment: @Opal That's the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the null safe operator:

```
def getValuesByStatus(def jsonData, String status ) {
    jsonData.findAll { json->
        json?.responseStatus?.status == status
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`jsonData` contains null values, but in debug mode you cant see those, so null value checking in findall closure helped.